# Reusing Zend validators on client-side

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework, zend-validate

I found this question on [another forum](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Tying-Dojo-and-Zend-form-validation-together-I-m-dreaming-right-tc1677380.html) where it didn't get any answers. I thought it was a good question worth asking here. I'm pasting it here word for word.

> Hi guys, I've got a pie in the sky
>   idea, and I'm just wondering if it's
>   even remotely possible, or if I should
>   give up and try something else.
>
> I've got a bunch of Zend_Dojo_Form
>   forms with a bunch of custom
>   validators on the Zend side - they
>   work fine, the form errors out when
>   values are incorrect, it's all working
>   exactly as you'd expect, however, what
>   I'd also like is for the same
>   validators to work on the Dojo client
>   side of the form - but without having
>   to completely re-implement them,
>   validator by validator.
>
> I understand that at its simplest
>   level, the Dojo isValid method doesn't
>   know or care about the application
>   behind it, and indeed for it to even
>   be able to get access to the errors in
>   the application it'd have to attempt a
>   submit, which isn't what it's meant to
>   do, but has anyone tried a system of
>   something like:
>
> 1. override form onSubmit to add our code
> 2. test Dojo isValid()
> 3. if the Dojo side is happy, AJAX submit the form
> 4. if successful, which would be returned i don't know how, then
>      forward on to the appropriate page
> 5. if not successful, then (and this is where it gets tricky I guess) pass
>      back enough data to know what field
>      errored out, what the error was, and
>      then call enough of the Dojo isValid
>      internal guts to make the form look
>      like it didn't validate?
>
> Sorry to just be airing ideas like
>   this, I just figured it might be
>   really useful if we could come up with
>   a way to sort of globally add custom
>   validators to our forms that work both
>   client and server side, without having
>   to implement them uniquely on both
>   sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meh, dojo :(

Use Jquery :)

Look at this, it's awesome:
[Ajaxify Your Zend_Form Validation with jQuery](http://www.zendcasts.com/ajaxify-your-zend_form-validation-with-jquery/2010/04/)

> We’re going to take what was put
>   together in the last 3 videos and now
>   include some server-side validation
>   that will appear asynchronously. This
>   is an example of using Zend_Form as a
>   validation tool via JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Zend_Form has a [`processAjax()`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/Zend_Form/Zend_Form.html#processAjax) method that can be used to validate any or all of a form's elements and return a JSON-encoded result (true, or a list of errors).

So this can be used to pre-validate all or part of the form in the onsubmit event handler; or even to pre-validate fields individually in their onchange event hander.

Comment: That process the form. I think the poster was more looking for a client-side validation using the same server validation code; if I understood correctly.

Comment: Here _process_ only means validation ;-) This is quite similar to what is done in the _“Ajaxify Your Zend_Form Validation with jQuery”_ link you posted.